# Weird hex entry in my Apache log

Tags: apache, logging, hex

What does this entry in my Apache log means? I would not care, as I see many weird entries in the log but always they have status 404 while this one has a 200 status, which means that whatever it was looking for, it found it, isn't right?

```
204.10.132.7 - - [26/Nov/2014:09:53:40 -0500] "\x06\xcf\x1a+\xc2x\x15\b\x85o#6\xbe>\x80\x9b\xdboi\x03\x99U\x06\xf8\xf86\xedw>\x81\xdf\xef\x18\xddb\xd4\xf5w\x89" 200 6466
```

An IP trace on the IP led me to a company - http://www.wpp.com/wpp/ - in NY:
http://www.ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/204.10.132.7

I understand that \x means a hexadecimal character but even so I can't figure out what that command means.

Thank you for any clarification.

Comment: I found the problem/solution, i have it open on a other pc, i will get back on it in a while, i am pretty busy...

Answer (score 1):

I found a decoder that does make a little more sence but it is still not clear what they are accesing.
The decoder is here https://paulschou.com/tools/xlate/

Answer (score 0):

I noticed it to, my search ended on Hex and binary, if i decode the Hex it does not make sence, so there for i think it is binary, and it is looking for folders and javascript and apache plugins.
becouse some results come back as 200 and others 400 or something like that.
They first check if the javascript is there or the plugin, then they come back in binary.
I realy want to know more about this, any one with information regarding this please talk to us.